# How to update database and div without reloading the page using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am very new to programming. I made a page with drop-downs, and by selecting the options I wish to update a field(score) in MySQL database and also in the div of the same page without actually reloading the whole page. Can someone please show me an example of how I can do it with Ajax? -Thanks

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_arrays)){
        $userid=$row['userid']; 
        $score=$row['score'];
        echo "                      
             <p><div class='user'><a href='#'><b>$userid</b></a></div>
             <p><div class='score'>Score: $score</div>   
             <form action ='' method = 'POST'>
               <select name='userscore' id='user_scores'>
               <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>
               </select>                   
               <input type='submit' value = 'Update Score' id= 'submit-score'/>
             </form>                         
             <br />
             ";
           }
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you can try Jquery`s ajax functionality, which is simple and easy to use.

Comment: Check here for examples: http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.in/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html; http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: The whole web is so full of such examples - just search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using JQuery

```
<script>
$("#user_scores").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("#user_scores option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + ",";
      });
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { values: str }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
})
.trigger('change');
</script>
```

more on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

some.php is your php file with script.

remember to bind "change" event after document is ready or your select code is loaded.

In some.php you should get these values in that way

```
$values = explode(",",$_POST['values']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use jQuery, you can read the documentation about ajax [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which is a good place to start.

Once you grasped the ajax concept, you just have to define the php script to be called by the ajax function. You have to pass the params you want to store and have the php script handle the saves. If you want you can echo some results, better if you encode them via `json_encode` which is a native PHP function.

To handle the results you'll define a javascript function which will be called on the success of the ajax call, which will perform the updates you need on your div based on the results received.

Sorry but I don't think that you will benefit from actual code, also because the internet is full of examples of each step i proposed you.

Comment: I also have difficult to find it, keywords for searching for it maybe too difficult .

Comment: @DavidAugustus what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, i tryed to say that this kind of technology is difficult to find at Google, because of searching keywords, i am trying to Google that for months, and i still cant learn a nice way to do a update at div values, using ajax, without realoding the page. I found a way ... but still not what i think that can be done ... And people anwering "Dont you know Google" is the worst kind of answer someone expects on this kind of researching ..

Comment: This is old, and stil not very clear, you got my point? Developers community could work for better examples, more clear stuff.. There is a long time i am searching for this.... I'm in Brazil, you know... I develop for a long time, but as the examples are difficult to test, and implement, i think this is not easy to do. If you have some time i could show you how i'm using it, and explain you better, that i am doing that to update a 2006  's gamming system written on PHP, with most actual technologies, and changing the concepts of user login, removing popups, flash, and page reloads ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php", // target url which is triggered upon ajax call
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } ,// The drop down selected val
success:function(response){
$('target_div').text(response); //updating the div content on successful ajax call
 //update database also. 
}
});
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make an AJAX call to update the data (using PHP) and the use the JQuery .load() function to update the

More on http://www.a100websolutions.in/ajax-php-database-update/

You can get a detailed tutorial here